# Is the activity stack saved to disk deleted If the app isn't opened again within a specified amount of time?

Tags: android, android-activity

App is killed by OS(low memory) and it's activity stack is saved to disk. If the app isn't opened again within a specified amount of time, is the activity stack on disk deleted? so when you reopen the app, it's as if you opened it for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> App is killed by OS(low memory) and it's activity stack is saved to disk

No, its task data, including the details of the back stack, is held onto in RAM. It's just that the RAM is owned by a core OS process, not the process that is being killed.

> If the app isn't opened again within a specified amount of time, is the activity stack on disk deleted?

If the user does not return to the app within ~30 minutes, the task data is released.

> so when you reopen the app, it's as if you opened it for the first time?

It will be as if the app were not already running. So, if you mean "first time in a while", then yes. If you mean "first time since the app was installed", then no — the app will still have whatever data that *it* stored on disk.